# в кали линукс не могу установить флешплеер

Tags: kali-linux

В кали линукс не могу установить флеш плеер из за того, что система не дает скопировать файлы,делаю все через графический интерфейс, опции копировать и вставить заблочены. Подскажите пожалуйста поэтапно что и как делать. Спасибо, всем добра!

Comment: Попробуйте выполнять копирование файла (-ов) с помощью терминала и прав root'а.

Comment: напишите пример пжлста

Comment: Если ответ был вам полезен, отметьте как "правильный".

Comment: Kali и флешплеер. Спс за вопрос, повеселили с самого утра. You made my day, как говорят англичане. Примите ответ, там все что вам нужно. И еще, как раз вчера был на ивенте, там одни из вопросов были по кибербезопасности. Рекомендация такая, сделайте сначала из своего ПК крепость (насколько это возможно), изучите все тонкости, а дальше уже вы и сами поймете, что к  чему. Дерзайте, в любом случае лучше хоть куда-то двигаться, чем стоять на месте. Хотите разобраться но не знаете куда смотреть, пойдите на курсы, только серьезные, что-то вроде Cisco.

Comment: братки спасибо всем, все сделал)

Comment: там кто то написал про курсы CUsko  вроде...) а в домашних условиях. как то интерОктивно можно изучать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выполнять команды с правами *root* (в терминале), можно написать `sudo` перед командами или просто команду `su -` и работать как `root` (но это не рекомендуется).

Команда для копирования файлов имеет следующий вид:

```
cp <файл+расширение/или путь до файла+файл+расширение> <путь куда копируем>
```

Пример:

```
sudo cp 1.txt usr/bin
```

Comment: Если ТС не может установить флешплеер, то я сомневаюсь, что он создал юзера, а не сидит под рутом). Так что, про рут вы ему зря вещаете. Я уверен, этот хацкер сидит уже под рутом... И еще долго будет запускать систему с данными root/toor

Comment: misdeed, в kali разве по defalt'у при установке не просит создать пользователя?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Любой мамкин хацкер должен знать, что под рутом сидеть нельзя. А если хацкер этого не знает - то он просто нуб!

Comment: Kali стал интересен молодежи только после сериала "Мистер Робот", до этого что-то особой активности не было (сейчас же каждый, кто ставит себе данный дестибутив считает себя всемогущим) Плохо это или хорошо, время покажет. Просто порой это веселит.

Comment: Vlad Spirin, полностью солидарен с вами) Да ещё и каналов/чатов в телеге "для хакеров" сколько)

Comment: други, сижу в USRе. Не под root ом.

Comment: интересует как в граф интерф можно все это сделать, а не через терминал

Comment: Зачем вам ОС на ядре Linux, если вы терминалом не пользуетесь? Вопрос риторический, можете не отвечать.

Comment: хакеры гуйнёй не пользуются, уважаемый... хакер! Так что, либо ставьте вантуз, либо бубунту)

Comment: спс за содействие, начал пользоваться терм-м

Comment: самое время начаться пользоваться README.txt для каждого устанавливаемого пакета) и будет вам счастье!